# cant use stream which is promise of getusermedia outside function

Tags: javascript, getusermedia

I am trying to record audio in webbrowser with this [tutorial](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/08/13/developing-speech-interface-for-xsa-web-applications-using-python/)

I am using getusermedia.

I can not able to use micstream outside the fuction.

```
var rec
var context = new AudioContext();

document.querySelector('#startrecord').addEventListener('click', () => {
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: true,
        video: false
    }).then((micStream) => {
        var microphone = context.createMediaStreamSource(micStream);
        rec = new Recorder(microphone, {
            numChannels: 1
        });
        rec.record();
        console.log('Started recording');
    });
});

document.querySelector('#stoprecord').addEventListener('click', stopRecording);
function stopRecording(){
    rec.stop(); //stop recording
    console.log('Stopped recording.');

    micStream.getAudioTracks()[0].stop();   //turn off mic
    rec.exportWAV(shareAudio);      //wave encode and share
}

function shareAudio(blob){
    //send blob over to python using web sockets
}
```

my console output is

```
Started recording(index):28 
Stopped recording.(index):35 
Uncaught ReferenceError: micStream is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.stopRecording ((index):37)
```

index 37 is 
    `micStream.getAudioTracks()[0].stop();  //turn off mic`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do the same thing you are doing with `rec` and the recorder:

```
var rec, mic;
...
    }).then((micStream) => {
        mic = micStream;//now available outside function scope like rec
...
       mic.getAudioTracks()[0].stop();   //turn off mic
```